# Change the font of the dates column in moderncv

Tags: fonts, moderncv

I have searched a lot but I have not found a way to change the font of the dates below every horizontal line of every section.

I use `moderncv` classic theme with `fontspec` and `fontawesome`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to redefine `hintfont`. As you are using `fontspec`, the following:

```
\newfontfamily\bio[Ligatures=TeX]{Linux Biolinum}% this only works if you are using fontspec under Xe- or LuaLaTex
\renewcommand*{\hintfont}{\bio\small\mdseries\itshape}
```

would for example make the dates be printed using Linux Biolinum in small, regular weight and italic.